# Is there a way to generate dynamic params to feed a C++ function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a class runner that accepts a different number of parameters.

Here is how I currently do it.

```
template<typename T, int params, typename std::enable_if<params == 1, int*>::type = nullptr>
void run(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.output.size(); i++)
        run(t, t.output[i], t.input1[i]);
}

template<typename T, int params, typename std::enable_if<params == 2, int*>::type = nullptr>
void run(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.output.size(); i++)
        run(t, t.output[i], t.input1[i], t.input2[i]);
}

template<typename T, int params, typename std::enable_if<params == 3, int*>::type = nullptr>
void run(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.output.size(); i++)
        run(t, t.output[i], t.input1[i], t.input2[i], t.input3[i]);
}

template<typename T, int params, typename std::enable_if<params == 4, int*>::type = nullptr>
void run(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.output.size(); i++)
        run(t, t.output[i], t.input1[i], t.input2[i], t.input3[i], t.input4[i]);
}
```

I had to write 4 functions to check for 4 input variants, while the structure is actually consistent so I'm wondering if there is someway to combine these into 1 generic function that can actually handle a dynamic number of inputs using this same pattern?

What I'm looking for is a way to unpack a given number to range so for example given 3 I get in input1, input2, input3

Comment: can't you make run accept an `std::array` or make the inputs a `std::tuple`? There is no good way to do this with individually named members

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the params have different types so std::array won't work, and they can be any number so std::tuple won't either.

Comment: could you elaborate on what the different input members of T are? could you also express them as a tuple (for a concrete type T that is, so varying member count wouldn't be a problem here)?

Comment: "and they can be any number so std::tuple won't either." why not? You already have different functions for different number of params. `std::tuple` will just make it simpler because then you only need 1 template rather than n different ones

Comment: @MohammadAbouElSherbini *and they can be any number so std::tuple won't either.* -- Then you aren't familiar with the `std::tuple` member functions or usage if you are saying this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you provide an example? All I know is that `std::tuple` is just a generalization of `std::pair` that takes 3 params.
I'm guessing that is wrong?

Comment: `std::tuple` is a generalization of `std::pair` that takes any number of parameters >= 0.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps variadic template arguments is what you’re looking for

Comment: Please be more specific. In particular, you can provide some code to support your idea.

Comment: You can't pass `.input3` as a template parameter nor deduce it. You could pass a series of getter functions or member pointers. But that would all change the interface. And if you have to do that then an array or tuple would be better.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Instead of passing getter functions, you can specialize `std::get` and `std::tuple_size`, and then use an index sequence.